# How do I type-hint __call() magic method in PHP?

Tags: php, type-hinting, method-call

I am implementing an [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for testing purposes, and I would like to type hint the return of the Adapter with the methods of two distinct classes, how can I achieve that?

```
class Foo {
  public function somethingOnlyFooHave() {};
}

class Adapter {
  protected $handler;

  public function __construct(object $handler) {
    $this->handler = $handler;
  }

  public function __call($name, ...$args) {
    $this->handler->$name($args);
  }

  public function somethingOnlyTheAdapterHave() {}
}

$foo = new Adapter(new Foo);

// How can I get type-hinting for both the Adapter and Foo?
$foo->somethingOnlyFooHave();
$foo->somethingOnlyTheAdapterHave();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems PHP can't do this natively, but If you're using PHPStorm 2018.3+, you can use Union Types (or Intersection Types), as long as it's not on the `__construct`:

```
class Foo {
    public function somethingOnlyFooHave() {}
}

class Adapter {
    protected $handler;

    public function __construct(object $handler) {
        $this->handler = $handler;
    }

    public function __call($name, ...$args) {
        $this->handler->$name($args);
    }

    /**
     * @return Adapter|Foo
     */
    public function get() {
        return $this;
    }

    public function somethingOnlyAdapterHave() {}
}

$foo_adapter = ( new Adapter(new Foo) )->get();

// The following methods receives type-hinting:
$foo_adapter->somethingOnlyFooHave();
$foo_adapter->somethingOnlyAdapterHave();
```

Useful links:

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/09/phpstorm-2018-3-eap-183-2635-12/#intersection-types
- https://medium.com/@ondrejmirtes/union-types-vs-intersection-types-fd44a8eacbb

Comment: Your question doesn't mention PHPStorm at all, so not sure how someone might come to this solution from it.

Comment: @NigelRen if you have another solution that doesn't use PHPStorm, I would love to hear it...

Comment: Because, as far as I know, PHP can't do this natively.

Comment: Did you just ask a question and then answer it within 1 minute?

Comment: I also think your example needs updating as it shows it defining the return type of the constructor - which doesn't return a value.

Comment: @lufc yes, you can add an answer while writing a question. I did this because I couldn't find this information on Stackoverflow and wanted to share the solution I came up to after some considerable investigation.

Comment: @lufc open a request to remove the answer-while-asking feature to Stackoverflow staff.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks, indeed the union type return doesn't seem to work on the constructor. In my actual code I was getting an instance using `Adapter::get()`.I have updated the answer.

Comment: @lufc Answering your own question is encouraged on Stack Overflow. If you have found an answer to your own problem you can share it with others here. This is what this site is for.